# Does calling .Last() on an IList iterate the entire list?

Tags: c#

Does the `.Last()` extension method take into account if it's called on an `IList`?  I'm just wondering if there's a significant performance difference between these:

```
IList<int> numbers = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };

int lastNumber1 = numbers.Last();
int lastNumber2 = numbers[numbers.Count-1];
```

Intuition tells me that the first alternative is O(n) but the second is O(1).  Is `.Last()` "smart" enough to try casting it to an `IList`?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Probably not, as it can do `list[list.count-1]`

Verified by reflector:

```
public static TSource Last<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source)
{
    if (source == null)
    {
        throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
    }
    IList<TSource> list = source as IList<TSource>;
    if (list != null)
    {
        int count = list.Count;
        if (count > 0)
        {
            return list[count - 1];
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  What I really learned is I'm a nut for not having .NET Reflector installed, after all this time.  :)

Answer (score 6):

This is an *undocumented* optimization, but the predicate-less overload of `Enumerable.Last` does indeed skip straight to the end.

Note that the overload *with* a predicate doesn't just go from the end, working backwards as you might expect - it goes forwards from the start. I believe this is to avoid inconsistency when the predicate may throw an exception (or cause other side effects).

See my [blog post about implementing First/Last/Single etc](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/12/29/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-11-first-single-last-and-the-ordefault-versions) for more information - and an inconsistency which *is* present between the overloads of Single/SingleOrDefault.

Comment: That's a good extra point.  I would also expect they do that because the predicate could cause side effects (other than throwing exceptions).

Comment: @Scott: True. Have edited to include that. On the other hand, the indexer/iterators *could* have side-effects too... it's all a bit of a mess :(

Comment: wow, I didn't think about that.  If you think about it, even if a predicate does lazy evaluation, you don't *want* it to evaluate all of them... that's the point of lazy evaluation.  You're right, it's a real mess.

Comment: Link no longer works.

Comment: @Casey: Fixed it now.

Answer (score 3):

Reflector:

```
public static TSource Last<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source)
{
    ...
    if (list != null)
    {
        int count = list.Count;
        if (count > 0)
        {
            return list[count - 1];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        using (IEnumerator<TSource> enumerator = source.GetEnumerator())
        {
            ...
        }
    }
    throw Error.NoElements();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Answer: Yes.

Here's a neat way to find out:

```
class MyList<T> : IList<T> { 
    private readonly List<T> list = new List<T>();
    public T this[int index] {
        get {
            Console.WriteLine("Inside indexer!");
            return list[index];
        }
        set {
            list[index] = value;
        }
    }

    public void Add(T item) {
        this.list.Add(item);
    }

    public int Count {
        get {
            Console.WriteLine("Inside Count!");
            return this.list.Count;
        }
    }

    // all other IList<T> interface members throw NotImplementedException
}
```

Then:

```
MyList<int> list = new MyList<int>();
list.Add(1);
list.Add(2);
Console.WriteLine(list.Last());
```

Output:

```
Inside Count!
Inside indexer!
2
```

If you try this:

```
Console.WriteLine(list.Last(n => n % 2 == 0));
```

then you get an exception in `GetEnumerator` showing that it is trying to walk the list. If we implement `GetEnumerator` via

```
public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator() {
    Console.WriteLine("Inside GetEnumerator");
    return this.list.GetEnumerator();
}
```

and try again we see

```
Inside GetEnumerator!
2
```

on the console showing that the indexer was never used.

Answer (score 0):

Original poster is talking about an interface, not the implementation.

So it depends on the the underlying implementation behind the `IList/Ilist<T>` in question. You don't how how its indexer is implemented. I believe the framework's `List<T>` has a concrete implementation that utilizes an array, so a direct lookup is possible, but if all you have is an reference to `IList<T>`, that is not a given by any means.

Comment: Technically true, but since the IList interface contains an indexer, it would stand to reason that in most cases list[i] would be o(1) (direct access)

Comment: So...something that **looks** like an array **is** an array? I think not. Don't confuse interface with implementation. It's safe to say that _some_ of the standard framework classes that implement `IList<T>` are O(1), but that's a far cry from making a blanket assertion. Without knowing something about implementation details, you can't say anything about the question as posed, with the caveat that, for his example, where the backing implementation is an array,  it's a safe bet Last() will give you O(1).

Comment: speaks the truth here. There are at least as many implementations of `IList<T>` that are not `O(1)` as there implementations that are `O(1)`. For any implementation that is `O(1)` I can just wrap it in a class that implements `IList<T>` and sleeps for an amount of time that proportional to `n` (here `n` is the `Count`). There are lots of really bad implementations of `IList<T>`. You can argue all you want that these aren't realistic but the point is that they exist, and they negate any assertion that `IList<T>` is `O(1)` random access.

Comment: The larger point is that interfaces are about what methods you can invoke, but there is no implicit contract about the implementation details. Just because someone hands you a something that implements `IDbConnection` doesn't mean it actually is an object that wraps a connection to a database. It just has methods that make it look like something that connects to a database.