# Save data of an updating variable C#

Tags: c#, .net

I have a variable called in_data which updates every second. I want to save this data into an array or list. The number of data received cannot be defined . Is there a way for me to save this indefinite number of data ????

For example lets say i have 11 data value changes for the in_data variable. I want to store all of them so that i can use that data for later manipulations.

Thank You in advance.

in_data = myport.ReadLine();

myCollection = new List();

myCollection.Add(in_data);

but this only saves the last instance of the data,, i want all the data that    was received to be saved

Comment: I think you said it with the word list...

Comment: Show relevant code. Explain what you have tried.

Comment: Could you give us more details and code example what you try to do. Did you have problems with adding to list or what?

Comment: What *Type* is `in_data` ?

Comment: in_data is of type string

Comment: A database or file (if persistent storage is needed), a List<string> if not

Comment: Kirill Bestemyanov :                                                                                 Well yes i tried,    myCollection = new List<string>();                       myCollection.Add(in_data);    but this only saves the last instance of the data,, i want all the data that was received to be saved

Comment: can you please be kind enough to show me how to use a list to store all the changes that are made to in_data

Comment: What is in_data? is it property or field of any class or what?

Comment: in_data is a string variable Sir

Comment: Because you are calling myCollection = new List(); every time after getting new value the list gets re-created and it becomes empty. Then you add new item to list and because of that list has only last instance of data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use List object.
Define it like:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
```

and then later just use:

```
list.Add(in_data);
```

Comment: yes but this only saves the last instance of the in_data ,,, i want to save all the data that was received

Comment: Every time you get the new value with myport.ReadLine(); you just use list.Add method to add that value to the list. The creating of list should be done only once at beggining.

Answer (score 0):

It is not very clear how in_data is updated. But assuming that you have access to that code, you could create a property instead of in_data as follows:

```
public readonly List<string> in_data_history = new List<string>();

public string in_data
{
     get {return in_data_history.Last();}
     set {in_data_history.Add(value);}
}
```

The getter for this property will return the last value of in_data. The setter will store all new values in in_data_history.

Comment: If i where you, i would not use linq extension method Last<T>() to get value. It gets time proportional to namber of elements in collection. You should place current value in different variable.

Comment: in_data = myport.ReadLine();    this is the way in which in_data is being updated sir

Comment: @Kirill Bestemyanov: A List already knows its length and the parameterless version of Last does not need to perform checks on each element, so I would expect it to perform in T(1) rather than T(N). Unfortunately [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb358775(v=vs.90).aspx) does not mention its performance.

Comment: @user2766227: If you can replace the definition of in_data with the code above, the list in_data_history will track all values of in_data. This works because whenever in_data = myport.ReadLine() is called the setter defined above is invoked adding the latest value into in_data_history.

Comment: @Can Bud: Cause List<T> does not have method Last(), it will be used extension method of IEnumerable interface. So it will work for O(n). I look at realization of this method now.

Comment: @KirillBestemyanov: It seems that this issue has been discussed before, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1377864/what-is-the-performance-of-the-last-extension-method-for-listt) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4833220/does-calling-last-on-an-ilist-iterate-the-entire-list).

Comment: For this use case I think that a `Stack<T>` would be a better suit than `List<T>`

Comment: A stack and a list are rather similar. This use case adds like a push, but it never pops or peeks. Considering that the intent is to keep a history, I believe that the access to the collection will suit a list.

Answer (score 0):

You can read all lines with this in your string in_data:

```
in_data = myport.ReadToEnd();
```

Or you can use a loop:

```
myCollection = new List(); 
while ((in_data = myport.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    myCollection.Add(in_data);
}
```